# Change Paginator arrow (next and previous pages ) color

Tags: css, pagination

I want to change the color of Paginator Arrows(next and previous pages), as you can see the arrow are invisible

[image: My Paginator]

This is my CSS file, what should I add ?

```
 body .ui-datatable .ui-paginator.ui-paginator-bottom {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

body .ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with arrows? And what have you tried?

Comment: Arrows(next and previous pages), I do not know what should I add to my CSS file to change the color of these arrows

Comment: Well you will first need to show the actual markup for the pagination.